# How to understand this example from Hull's book?

Tags: options, delta

I just started reading Hull's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133456315), and I got stuck in an example where a financial institution has sold for $300,000 a European call option on 100,000 shares of a non-dividend-paying stock.

- Stock price is 49
- Strike price is 50
- $r$ is 0.05,
- vol is 20%,
- $T$ is 0.3846

The example says

> Initially, the value of the written option is 240,000. In the
>   situation depicted in Table 18.2, the value of the option can be
>   calculated as 414,500 in Week 9. Thus, the financial institution has
>   lost 174,500 on its short option position. Its cash position, as
>   measured by the cumulative cost, is 1,442,900 worse in Week 9 than in
>   Week 0. The value of the shares held has increased from 2,557,800 to
>   4,171,100. The net effect of all this is that the value of the
>   financial institution’s position has changed by only 4,100 between
>   Week 0 and Week 9.

table 18.2 is as follow,
[image: table 18.2]

My question is: where did the numbers  *4,171,100* and *4,100* come from?

Comment: Wow this is a very basic question which probably should be closed so I hope the answer satisfies you and we can quickly make this question as answered.

Comment: Sorry i know this is very basic haha, thanks for editing this question for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compute the cumulative sum of the 'Shares Purchased' column you will find that in Week 9 the company owns a total of 78,700 shares. Each share is worth 53.00 (see 'Stock Price' column), so the value of the shares held in Week 9 is 78700*53 = 4,171,100.

The *increase* in share value is 4,171,100-2,557,800 = 1,613,300

The loss in the option position is -174,500

The debit in the cash position is -1,442,900 (=4,000,700-2,557,800 in the 6th column)

Combining these three elements (one positive and two negatives) we have 4100 dollars.